# TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${val}\` is not ` +

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my code where I have created an user model using nodejs, express, mongoose. But I am facing some problem in my user model when I am using it in the user controller:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const crypto = require('crypto');

//user schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      max: 32,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    hashed_password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: 'subscriber',
    },
    resetPasswordLink: {
      data: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

//virtual
userSchema
  .virtual('password')
  .set(function (password) {
    // create a temporarily variable called _password
    this._password = password;
    // generate salt
    this.salt = this.makeSalt();
    // encryptPassword
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function () {
    return this._password;
  });

//methods
userSchema.methods = {
  authenticate: function (plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
  },

  encryptPassword: function (password) {
    if (!password) return '';
    try {
      return crypto
        .createHmac('sha1', this.salt)
        .update(password)
        .digest('hex');
    } catch (err) {
      return '';
    }
  },

  makeSalt: function () {
    return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random()) + '';
  },
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I am facing this problem:
TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${val}` is not ` +

Can someone help me out?

I have created a user model in Node.js and imported it in the user controller. However,  I'm encountering a type error problem and I can't understand the problem.

Comment: Can you show the full error stack?

Comment: throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${val}\` is not ` +        
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `` is not a valid type at path `default`. See  for a list of valid schema types.